# Date conversion in java?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I have this date:2/23/2016 4:28:46 PM

```
String d="2/23/2016 4:28:46 PM";
Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
try {
    Date date = ((DateFormat) formatter).parse(d);
    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM HH:mm a");
    String notDate = formatter.format(date);
    holder.tvNotificationTime.setText(notDate);
    System.out.println(notDate);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I want the output as

```
23 Feb 4:28 PM
```

But I get output as

```
23 Feb 04:28 am
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: Do you asking about why date switched from PM to AM?

Comment: I wonder why you ignore the "PM" while parsing the string ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use one `H` in the second `DateFormat` object:

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM h:mm a");
```

You also need to the AM/PM marker for the first formatter:

```
Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
```

See this note from the [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

> **Number:** For formatting, the number of pattern letters is the minimum number of digits, and **shorter numbers are zero-padded to this amount**. For parsing, the number of pattern letters is ignored unless it's needed to separate two adjacent fields.

Answer (score 1):

```
How about this:

        Date date1 = new Date("2/23/2016 4:28:46 PM");
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM hh:mm:ss a");
        String formattedDate = sdf.format(date1);
        System.out.println("Formatted Date: "+formattedDate);
```